# Upload large files (> 1 GB) to Azure Blob storage through web api

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, asp.net-core-webapi

We have an application (.NET core) that is hosted in Azure App Service and we are trying to upload large files to Azure Blob through web API using Form data from UI.

We have changed request length and API request timeout still we are facing connection time out errors even while uploading 200MB files.

Below is the sample code I am using:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 2147483648)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload([FromForm] FileRequestObject fileRequestObject)
{
    var url = "upload_url_to_blob_storage";
    var file = fileRequestObject.Files[0];

    var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(url));
    blob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;

    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.InputStream);

    //Some other operations based on file upload.
    return Ok();
}

public class FileRequestObject
{
    public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
    public string JSON { get; set; }
    public string BlobUrls { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it an option to use the API to generate the SAS token and then upload the file directly to the blob store?

Comment: Are you sure you're not hitting the Block Blob size limits for PUT operations?``` The maximum size for a block blob created via Put Blob is 256 MB for version 2016-05-31 and later, and 64 MB for older versions. If your blob is larger than 256 MB for version 2016-05-31 and later, or 64 MB for older versions, you must upload it as a set of blocks.``` For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob

Comment: @kgalic no, we have complete upload operation is in API, we are passing stream data to the API endpoint and then from there uploading to blob

Comment: Do we get timeout errors if Block Blob size limits exceeds

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy, please share us the code you're using, and remove the personal data / secret.

Comment: @IvanYang added the code, please have a look

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy Could you please tell me how you define FileRequestObject  classs?

Comment: @JimXu updated the FileRequestObject

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy Ok. I will check it

Answer (score 12):

According to your code, you want to upload a large file to Azure blob storage as blockblob. Please note that it has a limitation. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob#remarks):

> The maximum size for a block blob created via Put Blob is 256 MB for
> version 2016-05-31 and later, and 64 MB for older versions. If your
> blob is larger than 256 MB for version 2016-05-31 and later, or 64 MB
> for older versions, you must upload it as a set of blocks

So If you want to large files to azure block blob, pleae use the following steps:

#### 1. Read the whole file to bytes, and divide the file into smaller pieces in your code.

- Maybe 8 MB for each pieces.

#### 2. Upload each piece with [Put Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob#remarks) API.

- In each request, it contains a blockid.

#### 3. Make up the blob with [Put Block List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) API.

- In this request, you need to put all the blockid in the body in ordered.

For example:

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 2147483648)]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsync([FromForm]FileRequestObject fileRequestObject)
{
    var storageAccountConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=blobstorage0516;AccountKey=UVOOBCxQpr5BVueU+scUeVG/61CZbZmj9ymouAR9609WbqJhhma2N+WL/hvaoNs4p4DJobmT0F0KAs0hdtPcqA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

    var StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccountConnectionString);
    var BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var Container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
    
    await Container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    
    var blob = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileRequestObject.File.FileName);

    HashSet<string> blocklist = new HashSet<string>();

    var file = fileRequestObject.File;
    const int pageSizeInBytes = 10485760;
    long prevLastByte = 0;
    long bytesRemain = file.Length;
    byte[] bytes;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream();
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
        bytes = ms.ToArray();
    }

    //Upload each piece.
    do
    {
        long bytesToCopy = Math.Min(bytesRemain, pageSizeInBytes);
        byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[bytesToCopy];
        
        Array.Copy(bytes, prevLastByte, bytesToSend, 0, bytesToCopy);
        prevLastByte += bytesToCopy;
        bytesRemain -= bytesToCopy;

        //Create blockId
        string blockId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string base64BlockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId));

        await blob.PutBlockAsync(base64BlockId, new MemoryStream(bytesToSend, true), null);

        blocklist.Add(base64BlockId);

    } while (bytesRemain > 0);

    //post blocklist
    await blob.PutBlockListAsync(blocklist);

    //For more information on protecting this API from Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=717803
    return Ok();
}

public class FileRequestObject
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

[image]
[image]

For more details, please refer to:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/

Comment: it worked for me without "writable" i.e. `MemoryStream(bytesToSend)`

Comment: @Jim Xu  I want to upload more than 1gb file, by using this code it took more than 50min time to upload, Any faster way to upload a file